# To get the length of a javascript object

Tags: javascript, jquery

If I have a JavaScript object, say

```
data
:
Array[1]
 0
 :
 Object
  section
  :
  Array[6]
  tool
  :
  Array[6]
  wellcon
  :
  Array[6]
  welltra
  Array[6]
```

from this how i get the section length.
i try like

> data.section.length

but this is wrong. 
what is the wrong in my syntax?

Comment: can you, please post in whole object?

Comment: please add the data as JSON string with spacer.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Length of a JavaScript object](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5223/length-of-a-javascript-object)

Comment: check with this : Object.keys(data).length

Comment: Try data[0].section.length

Comment: Please add a proper json

Comment: You must share entire object .

Comment: Format your code properly, its very hard to read

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `data[0].section.length`
I think it is answer

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
 Object.keys(data).length
```

or you can find it in another way

```
Object.size = function(obj) {
var size = 0, key;
for (key in obj) {
    if (obj.hasOwnProperty(key)) size++;
}
return size;
};

var size = Object.size(data);//length of the data
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are looking for this:

```
Object.keys(data.section).length
```

or

```
Object.entries(data.section).length
```

but this way is experimental thing, described [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries)